# Why is float:left required in navigation to keep text center when position:absolute applied to header?

Tags: css, css-float, css-position

Observed a strange thing with `CSS position : absolute` in header is that unless there is a `float:left` in the menu below, the text of the menu is not centered vertically and stays at the top. You can see this by running the snippet given in this page and in full width. I have put a media query for `float:none in lower screen width` which cancels the `float:left` in higher screen-widths.

Now, why is this behaviour ? Why is float:left keeping the menu text center vertically when position:absolute is applied to header and vice-versa ? I did not find anything on this on searching.

**Edit -**

Some answers are saying that this is happening due to "collapsing" of margins. But they are not explaining why the `h1 of header` is not "collapsing" and behaving this way ? Why only the `h1 of menu` is "collapsing" ? It seems more of a selecting overlapping of some elements rather than collapsing.

**Edit2**-

Request the answer givers that if they want to break up the snippet for convenience of their explanations, they should also put in their answer the full snippet or its modification besides the parts of snippet. Because divs do not act in isolation. The answer should have the header with position: absolute, its h1 and the margin-top applied to the h1 of the div below the header.

Please see this snippet -

```css
div.header {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #EE82EE;
    background-color: #000000;
}
.submenu {
 text-align: center;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  margin-top: 72px;
  color:black;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  padding:0px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 766px){
  .submenu {
   float:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
 <h1>HEADER </h1>
</div>
<div class="submenu">
  <h1>MENU</h1>
  
</div>
```

Comment: The float is doing nothing since the width is 100%.

Comment: @Paulie_D Please see the difference in the snippet in different screenwidths by adjusting your browser. In smaller width where `float:none` is applied, the text of the menu goes upwards and does not remain center. Why is that ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `position: absolute` applied to the header makes the div FIXED while all other divs become relatively MOVABLE. So, to make the others also fixed, we give them some other properties like display:inline-block, float:left etc.

Also, need to give a margin-top to the div below the absolute div to offset the collapsing margin

Please see working code with these fixes applied and which has all the divs at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QqRgRB

The snippet is as follows -

```css
div.header {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #EE82EE;
    background-color: grey;
}
.menu {
 text-align: center;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  margin-top: 72px;
  color:black;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  padding:0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.submenu {
   text-align: center;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  margin-top: 0px;
  color:black;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 766px){
  .menu {
   float:none;
  }
}
body {
  margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
 <h1>HEADER </h1>
</div>
<div class="menu">
  <h1>MENU</h1>
  
</div>

<div class="submenu">
  <h1>SUBMENU</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**:

As I explained in my comments, the `h1` in your header doesn't collapse because it uses `position:absolute` - which, as you can see below, is one of the fixes to prevent collapsing margins. The overlapping is only happening because your header is absolutely positioned, so it will appear on top of everything else in the page.

To summarise loosely, **collapsing margins** happen when *vertical* margins touch on *block* elements that have *no separation* between them (e.g. borders or padding), are *not floated*, *not absolutely positioned*, *not fixed* and have *`overflow:visible`* (the default value). There are some other cases but that covers the vast majority causes, including yours.

---

**Answer**

What you're seeing is the effect of **collapsing margins**.

The CSS spec says that when the vertical margins of two elements touch, the two margins will be combined to form a single margin.

This also occurs with parent/child elements when there is no separation between the first (or last) child and the parent - in this case the collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

**In your case**, your `h1` has a default margin from the browsers stylesheet. This is being collapsed into its parent's margin i.e. the `submenu` element by default because it is a block element.

**Prevent margin collapsing**: 
There are a number of ways to prevent a margin of the child from collapsing including:

- float
- position: absolute.
- change the display to one of: “table-cell”, “table-caption”, or “inline-block".
- add an overflow other than visible, e.g. `overflow:auto`
- add a "separation" between the parent and child, e.g. a border or padding.

When you add the `float` to your child, this is one of the methods that prevent the margins from collapsing, so you still have the space from the margin appearing at the top of your h1 that contains the word "Menu".

**See some examples:**

```css
.submenu {
 text-align: center;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  margin-top: 0px;
  color:black;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  float: none;
  padding:0px;
}
.container { border:2px solid #ff0;}
.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
h1{ margin:30px 0;}
.submenu.hasfloat {float: left;}
.submenu.hasoverflow {overflow: auto;}
```

```html
<p>The top margin of this h1 is collapsed into the parent's margin. </p><p>The parent's top margin is 10px, and the h1 has a top margin of 30px, so when collapsed the parent now takes on the child's margin because it is larger - you can see the margin surrounded with the yellow border:</p>
<div class="container">
<div class="submenu">
  <h1>Collapsed</h1>
</div>
</div>
<p>The top margin of this h1 isn't collapsing because the parent is <b>floated</b>:</p>
<div class="container">
<div class="submenu hasfloat">
  <h1>Not collapsed</h1>
</div>
</div>
<p>The top margin of this h1 isn't collapsing because the parent has <b>overflow:auto</b> (i.e. any value other than visible):</p>
<div class="container">
<div class="submenu hasoverflow">
  <h1>Not collapsed</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

Example: Showing that the issue still exists even if the header is not absolutely positioned.

```css
div.header {
    position: relative;
    left: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #EE82EE;
    background-color: #000000;
}
.submenu {
 text-align: center;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  margin-top: 72px;
  color:black;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  padding:0px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 766px){
  .submenu {
   float:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
 <h1>HEADER <small>- position:relative</small></h1>
</div>
<div class="submenu">
  <h1>MENU <small>- top margin is still collapsing</small></h1>
  
</div>
```

**References**: Read more about collapsing margins from:

- [Mozilla.org: Mastering margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)
- [W3.org CSS3 Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)
- [Sitepoint: Collapsing Margins](https://www.sitepoint.com/collapsing-margins/)
- [CSS Tricks:What You Should Know About Collapsing Margins](https://css-tricks.com/what-you-should-know-about-collapsing-margins/)

Comment: This happens ONLY when header has `positoin:absolute`. Plaase explain with reference to that - that why when header has `position:absolute`, and there is no `float:left` etc. on the menu, why the menu text goes upwards ?

Comment: @user20152015 No, thats not the case - in the example you posted, if you remove `position:absolute` it still makes no difference to the position of the h1 in submenu - I've updated my answer to show you, see the second snippet in my answer. The header actually has no relevance at all to what's happening... as you can see in my examples, it happens even without the header at all.

Comment: This does not seem to have to do anything with the margins because if you increase the margin-bottom of the parent element or top element, still the text of menu goes up @FluffyKitten

Comment: @user20152015 I can *absolutely guarantee* you that it *is* to do with the margins. Not only have I proven that to you in the examples, it is also a well documented problem that many people run into. Of course changing the bottom margin doesn't make a difference - the problem is that the *top* margins are collapsing! I've given you a list of ways to solve the issue and examples - did you try any of them and did they work?

Comment: Change any margin and there will be no difference. This issue has nothing to do with collapsing margins.

Comment: Try to keep all margins of all elements same and still you will get the same result

Comment: @user20152015 ***Why are you changing the margins?*** That is ***not*** the way to fix the **collapsing margin issue**!! Because the problem is that they are **collapsing**. So changing them isn't going to help... they will still **collapse**! I've proven to you in my answer that this is the issue and the fixes in my answer will solve the problem - did you even try any of them? If you don't believe me, just research "collapsing margins" yourself. It is absolutely, definitely, 100% the collapsing margin issue that is causing this. I've given you examples to prove it. What more do you want?

Comment: From your answer `The CSS spec says that when the vertical margins of two elements touch, the two margins will be combined to form a single margin.` So, if I keep let us say 72px for ALL margins of ALL elements, then all elements should have equal touching margins and they should not overlap each other, which is not the case here. 
I already applied `float:left` in my question snippet itself. This question is more on why this happens rather than fixes.

Comment: And @FluffyKitten Please explain why this is not happening with the `h1 of the header` Why is it not "collapsing" also ? Why only the `h1 of the menu` is "collapsing" ?

Comment: @user20152015 My answer also says that for parent/child elements "***the collapsed margin ends up outside the parent***". This is what's happening for you - the top margin of your h1 is collapsing into the top margin of the submenu and theyre being combined outside of the parent... as I *already explained* in my answer. And as I *also* said in my answer, one of the ways to prevent collapsing margins is to use `position:absolute` - which your header is using. All of that was already explained - please read the full answer or explain what it is you don't understand before jumping to conclusions.

Comment: Please see Pen - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QqRgRB I added one more div below the menu div called `Submenu` You can see that the Submenu h1 is not overlapping. Can you explain this ?

Comment: @user20152015 Basically, it only happens under certain conditions: to vertical margins only, on block elements that have no separation between them (such as border or padding), are not floated, have overflow:visible (the default value), are not absolutely positioned, and a few other less common situations. **Edit**: in your pen, its not happening in submenu2 ***because it is floated***... one of the fixes in my answer!!!

Comment: O.k. I corrected the mistake in my pen. Why the divs are not overlapping with each other ? Why only the h1 of lower elements ? @FluffyKitten
Please put more than one div in your answer and explain this with respect to ALL elements, not just for one div and its child h1 which is unrealistic situation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157299/discussion-between-fluffykitten-and-user20152015).